# How to extract source branch from which pull request was raised to the present branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have bitbucket commit id and branch name post merging from another branch following  PR . How can I get  name of the source branch from which PR was raised from the above information ?

Comment: Is this a pull request made on bitbucket ? or Github ?

Comment: Yes, pull request made on bitbucket